Is presuppositional apologetics a form of circular reasoning?
I know a bit about classical apologetics (e.g the works of Richard Swinburne and W.L Craig) and evidential apologetics (e.g Gary Habermas, Mike Licona). Overall, I think the reasoning is clear. What I found a bit confusing is presuppositional apologetics.
Consider this:

You take the teachings of Scripture and act as if they are true
(which, of course, they are), even if they contradict what your
discussion partner is telling you.  In this way of apologetics, you
let Scripture tell you what is true about the unbeliever, his
challenges, what he already knows, and the whole conversation. And you
view the whole conversation through the lens of Scripture.
https://thethink.institute/articles/presupvsevidential

I remember learning some methods of proof on Discrete Math class many years ago, and one of them was proof by contradiction. If you want to prove Christianity is true, then start at the assumption that Christianity is false, and see if the consequence support that.
So, I wonder if the presuppositional folks are doing circular reasoning. Perhaps I misunderstand something about their approach, though.

All proofs begin with assumptions; presuppositions.  "The one who has received his testimony has set his seal to this; that God is true".  The presuppositionalist has first received a testimony.

@MikeBorden I know. But the reasoning is weird, both premise and conclusion is same: Christanity is true. Compare with classic apologetics, for example. The premise is not Christianity is true, but universe has a beginning. Sure, it doesn't specifically talk about Christian God, which means another argument is needed. I see no circular reasoning in that.

"Scientists don't try to prove or disprove God's existence because they know there isn't an experiment that can ever detect God. And if you believe in God, it doesn't matter what scientists discover about the universe – any cosmos can be thought of as being consistent with God.".  Does that help?

@MikeBorden Now this confuses me. What this has to do with the presuppositional approach?

It has more to do with why proof by contradiction won't work where God's existence is concerned.

My edit was merely to correct a typo. But when you ask "Is Christianity true?" that is aeons removed from asking "Is God true?" As Christianity can never exist without evidence that God is true, then that surely has to be the first, essential presupposition for if there is no God, then Christianity is false. But so are myriad other religions. To assume that God is false presupposes the reality of God. How many scientists are prepared to "Let God be found true, though every man a liar"? Romans 3:4

In any conversation, my baseline position is that I know God is true in the Christian sense.  This is not the result of any apologetic or reasoning power but, rather, the result of a new birth.
The Spirit of God convinced me of sin and my desperate need of a savior (long story), which drove me into the Bible (long story), which ultimately led me to abandon all else and call on the name of the Lord.  God, in Christ, did save me (just as the Bible says) and His Spirit, His testimony, took up residence within me.  I am neither the man I once was nor who I am yet to become.

If we receive the witness of men, the witness of God is greater: for this is the witness of God which he hath testified of his Son. He that believeth on the Son of God hath the witness in himself: he that believeth not God hath made him a liar; because he believeth not the record that God gave of his Son. And this is the record, that God hath given to us eternal life, and this life is in his Son. He that hath the Son hath life; and he that hath not the Son of God hath not life. These things have I written unto you that believe on the name of the Son of God; that ye may know that ye have eternal life, and that ye may believe on the name of the Son of God. - 1 John 5:9-13

"Christianity is true" may appear identical as both premise and conclusion within a process of reason (and thus somewhat circular) but the premise is actually separate.  Not separate from reason itself but the result of a separate reasoning process.
When a sinner is exposed before the Living God (there are various means but all through the one Spirit) and they see before them the grace of God offering salvation through faith in His Son, it is reasonable to leave everything that came before, to repent, and cling to Christ alone.  As the parable says, to sell all you have in order to gain the treasure.
Or as the Apostle Paul exhorts on the basis of what God has done in Christ:

I beseech you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that ye present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable unto God, which is your reasonable service. And be not conformed to this world: but be ye transformed by the renewing of your mind, that ye may prove what is that good, and acceptable, and perfect, will of God. - Romans 12:1-2

First, the conviction of the Spirit, then the living sacrifice/new birth, and then the transformation of the mind which results in obedience whereby the will of God is proven good, acceptable, and perfect.  The born again apologist has all of this as a proven true starting point.
So a non-believer partaking in a presuppositionalist apologetic conversation may have no choice but to view "Christianity is true" as both premise and conclusion but for the born again believer it is neither:  It is merely fact.
The difficulty comes in that it is not received or perceived as fact apart from the new birth, which is a spiritual reality rather than a logical process:

Jesus answered and said unto him, Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born again, he cannot see the kingdom of God. - John 3:3


"Not separate from reason itself but the result of a separate reasoning process." OK I think I'm seeing a bit of light: are you talking about "believing Christianity is true" vs "showing Christianity is true" ?

@anta40 Yes.  Something like that.  The born-again apologist has been convinced (by receiving the testimony) and is now offering a defense or apology in hopes of convincing or edifying others.  IMO it is not a primary evangelism means.  First one must live according to the hope that they have and then be prepared to explain it.  " But sanctify the Lord God in your hearts: and be ready always to give an answer to every man that asketh you a reason of the hope that is in you with meekness and fear" 1 Peter 3:15.

Insight from the Empirical Method of ModernityEmpirical Method An answer to this question may be found in an examination of the modern empirical method common in modern academia. (1) First recall that this method begins with an hypothesis, an assumption or presupposition.
(2) Then a set of predictions are drawn up: If such a hypothesis is true, then such and such truths (events, facts, etc.) should be true. Any experience (experiment) should support it. (This is the process of induction.)
(3) Then experiments are carried out (if it is a scientific hypothesis), or historical research is done (if it is a historical hypothesis), or spiritual inquiry (if it is a theological endeavor).
(4) After extensive research, Conclusions are drawn based on legitimate deductions, and valid analytical reasoning. The Hypothesis is either confirmed or denied.
PresuppositionalismWhen a theologian assumes the Bible to be true, or presumes that God exists, he is engaged in presuppositional approaches to truth. There is nothing wrong with this...IF IT IS BACKED UP with subsequent evidence to substantiate these presumptions. And there is indeed enough theological Providence by God (interaction by God with mankind) to substantiate this "faith" in the presupposition. [Consider Jesus's use of proofs: John 5:31-39; and Peter' s use of evidence: Acts 2:14-40]
If however, one's attitude to belief is: I believe because I believe it is true. And I don't need any proof to have faith, then that person is not engaging in reasonable, legitimate Faith in God.  With that posture, a person could claim to be a Buddhist, Shintoist, New Ager, or even atheist!
Goodness sakes. We don't even buy a car, choose a mate, or make life decisions, with that kind of approach.
Rather, the God who created the mind of man with reasoning powers, said Come, let us reason together. (It is also true that God aids man's reasoning with the Holy Spirit's drawing, though.)
The point of beginningAs someone has noted, everyone begins thinking with his or her presuppositions---either cultural, tribal, or educational. But one cannot stop there in any existential research. If so, they may indeed be engaging in "circular reasoning". [Apologetical evangelists have often challenged individuals to examine their "worldviews" and their presuppositions to see if they were valid when carried out to their logical conclusion.]
Josh McDowell recognized this, and presented an apologetic based on the presupposition that Jesus was indeed God. But he did not base his faith on this alone, but set up predictions which would be true only if Jesus were God. Jesus did indeed fulfil them, and there is therefore enough God-given reason to believe---and to dedicate and live one's life with "faith" in God's love in this life, and in the life to come.
Fortunately (providentially) we in modernity can have great reliance in the Scriptures as the Word of God, because of the many historical verifications by God's providence in human---and individual---history. As F. Schaeffer wrote, God is There and He is Not Silent.!
Resources"Presuppositionalism", Norman Geisler, BAKER ENCYCLOPEDIA OF CHRISTIAN APOLOGETICS.

Stephen Meyer, THE RETURN OF THE GOD HYPOTHESIS
Stephen Meyer, SIGNATURE IN THE CELL
Bernard Ramm, CHRISTIAN APOLOGETICS
Mortimer Adler, HOW TO THINK ABOUT GOD
Robert Jastrow, GOD AND THE ASTRONOMERS
Josh McDowell, EVIDENCE THAT DEMANDS A VERDICT


Presuppositionalists do not "substantiate their assumptions."  This proves that the answer has no understanding of Presuppositionalism.


Is presuppositional apologetics a form of circular reasoning?

Yes, it is.  The presuppositionalist refuses to doubt their own presuppositions, even for the sake of argument, and it is crucial to understand that these presuppositions are idiosyncratic and biased in favor of their own position.  Now to be fair, the presuppositionalist takes Scripture as the presupposition, not the per se truth of Christianity.  Nevertheless, at least by common consensus Scripture (i.e. the Christian canon) does attest to the truth of Christianity, and no non-Christian interlocutor will be willing to accept the absolute authority of Christian scripture.

For a Christian, the content of Scripture must serve as his ultimate
presupposition…
-Presuppositional Apologetics | Wikipedia

The presuppositionalist therefore refuses to argue from neutral premises or presuppositions, and this could serve as a definition of circular reasoning.  When two parties argue with one another they begin by agreeing to certain presuppositions of logic and inference, and then proceed to allow these presuppositions to control the arguments.  For the presuppositionalist there is no neutral controlling paradigm, and because of this any argument which contradicts their idiosyncratic Scriptural presuppositions must, by that very reason, be false.  By all appearances Presuppositionalism is a form of intransigence and refusal to enter into real argument.  (Because of this the reductio ad absurdum route that the questioner proposes is repugnant to the Presuppositionalist, who would rather reject the laws of logic before supposing--even for the sake of argument--that Christianity is false.)
Of course the Presuppositionalist does offer a meta-argument, namely the meta-argument that all argumentation is circular and there is no neutral ground from which to begin an argument.  If this were true then the fallacious circularity of Presuppositionalism would fare no worse than any other approach (but also no better!).  But of course it is false.  People argue all the time without falling into petitio principii.  Because argument is possible we know that the meta-argument of Presuppositionalism is false.  Indeed, if argument were not possible then the meta-argument itself could not be given.

Refusing to doubt the presuppositions would need to be demonstrated. So does the assertion that non-Christians don't do the exact same thing, as in my experience, they very much do do exactly the same thing.

This is, of course, assuming that the presuppositionalist has not actually met and entered into a relationship with the Living God.  Existence, after all, is binary.

@Matthew A presupposition is not a conclusion.  If someone is arguing for their axioms then they are not a Presuppositionalist.  It's that simple.

"Scripture is historically accurate". "Nothing supernatural exists". Please explain how one is an "axiom" while one is a "presupposition".
